# Smarty Templates - Return product info based on topic type

Tags: php, smarty

Im using the following code:

```
{foreach from=$entries key=i item=topic}
  {if $topic.topic_style == problem}
    <li>
      <a href="topic.php?id={$topic.id}">{$topic.title}</a>
    </li>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Which returns the topics which are all '`problem`'s.

Its possible to tag a problem with a product, the system uses the Get Satisfaction API.

I want to return the `product` associated with this `Topic`, if there is a product associated with this Topic.

I have the following, which returns all products:

```
{foreach from=$products key=i item=product}
  {$product.name}
{/foreach}
```

Im wondering if anyone might be able to work out how I can combine these two pieces of code to return the product associated with this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would you want to do this in smarty? it undermines the principle of using templates if you place so much php code in them
i'd suggest you create an multidimensional array like $array[topic_key]['producs'] and loop through that with smarty

Comment: This makes the most sense. This shouldn't be done in your templates really. Compile the data into an array first and then pass that to your template as Chrisitian says.